# Using sharepoint to pass credentials to other sites

Tags: sharepoint, single-sign-on, credentials

being completely new to the Sharepoint scene, I was wondering what basic solutions are to the problem I'm facing.

I have 2 different webapplications, which are both accessed by my clients by **different** logins.

I want to simplify things and let them just log in on a Sharepoint application, so they have 2 links on their portal to the webapplications, without having to login again, preferably without changing the existing webapplications.

Is this possible using the Secure Store Service in Sharepoint 2010? Or are there better options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using forms authentication, you can point sharepoint at the same authentication database as your other applications.

Comment: Well, apparently they're not using the same logins. So maybe this is possible using an SSO-like solution?

Comment: Probably easier in the long run to integrate all the authentication to a single shared forms auth database.

Comment: I have to agree with Nat, otherwise it's a nightmare. You should always consider the long-running support/maintanence implications

Answer (score 2):

What kind of authentication mechanism you use on your sites? Maybe you should consider using Windows Integrated Authentication and not handle the whole authentication issue at all?

Comment: I don't think that's possible since clients log in from outside the domain, from their own company or at home.

Comment: You can use forms authentication but have the function that handles authentication call the domain controller to check the login/password.  That way you can use one place to store all your logins.

Comment: I don't understand this solution completely. So I have Sharepoint use forms authentication, and then I add the two webapplications in sharepoint as "team sites" and when I do that there's a possibility to provide the login/passwords, since they're linked to the DC credentials from Sharepoint? Thanks for the input so far.